# How to convert a string to fixed point format?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, fixed-point

I'm doing basic fixedpoint math in batch.

In batch there are only operations on integer mathematics and the internal format of the variables is 32 bit maximum.

I'm trying to implement Q16.16 by putting the number in just one variable. And if it's possible I also wanted to implement with 2 integer variable for large value.

EDIT 3:*as written by [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) in the comments it would be a problem to do the multiplication in q16.16. So I will most likely reduce to Q15.15 but this is just a detail.*

The first difficulty I find is loading the variables. Let's start from Q16.16.

I have to transform a real number, represented by a string because the batch does not support real numbers, and insert it into a variable which can then be used with integer mathematics.

Eg "1234.5678"

The first part is simple because I separate the integer part, insert it into the number and multiply by 65536 or do a shift <<16

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set Num=1234.6789

For /F "Tokens=1-2 Delims=,." %%a in ("!Num!") Do (
Set Int=%%a
Set Fract=%%b
)

echo Num=!int!.!fract!

set /A "Num_Q=Int << 16"

echo Num_Q=!num_Q!

pause
```

The problem I have is converting the fractional part. How should I proceed?

Sorry if I framed the question incorrectly, but I am ready to correct it to meet the necessary requirements

EDIT: *I wanted to address the problem exclusively in cmd, not  powershell or vbscript, mshta or other*.

EDIT 2: *The final goal is to solve mathematical operations like: "sin(a * 0.123) * (13 + 5 / (.251 + pow(b * 4, 4))) - sin(b) * 55.25", but since I need a lot of speed I would like to use integer math as quickly as it is done in fixed point math. I have already developed 128bit multiplication operations [Batch Math](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5819&p=68668) with cmd and also with [Karatsuba](https://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?t=65). But they are very slow for my goal. Furthermore, the division is even slower. For division I am developing Knuth's method. But it's too slow and difficult.
So I need a hand to overcome this little obstacle.*

Comment: `dos` doesn't support arithmetic at all. You're speaking of `cmd` (the Windows command line), which does.

Comment: ok, thanks. But isn't the cmd command from microsoft dos?

Comment: it's from Microsoft. But it isn't DOS (looks the same, most commands are the same, but most behave different. Like there is `set` in DOS, but no `set /a` or `set /p`)

Comment: It should be noted that neither `!Int!` or `!Fract!` can resolve to greater than `32767` otherwise multiplying it by `65536` would exceed the 32-bit signed integer limit, _(`2147483647`)_, of the `Set /A` command. Personally I would include some logic in the code to determine such scenarios, and inform the end user if it does.

Comment: I'm not clear what the end goal is.  Are you wanting to be able to multiple two numbers such as `2345.67 * 9876.54321`?  If that is the goal, it should be possible, but the code will not be short and simple.  Decide what precision you want, lets say 4 places, so we convert it to `2345.6700 * 9876.5432`.  Remove the `.`, multiply, probably something like [this](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/multiply_3rdparty_bat.txt), getting `2316711108794400`, then insert `.` 8 places from right, getting `23167111.08794400`, and remove trailing `0`s.

Comment: The final goal is to solve mathematical operations like: "Math.sin(a * 7) * (13 + 5 / (.2 + Math.pow(b * 4, 4))) - Math.sin(b) * 50", but since I need a lot of speed I would like to use integer math as quickly as it is done in fixed point math. I have already developed 128bit multiplication operations "https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5819&p=68668" with cmd and also with karatsuba . But they are very slow for my goal Furthermore, the division is even slower. Now I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Thanks Compo. For overflow this may be the solution https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5499&p=33546

Answer (score 0):

I would use the help of PowerShell to do the math, because it doesn't have the strict restrictions, `cmd` has (PowerShell supports floating-point natively), making your life much easier:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "Num=2147483648.6789" & REM this is float and surely above INT32 range
call :calc %num% * 3
echo Result raw format:  %result%
REM in case you need a certain separator:
echo dot as separator:   %result:,=.%
echo comma as separator: %result:.=,%


goto :eof
:calc
For /F "Delims=" %%a in ('powershell %*') Do set "Result=%%a"
REM yes, that's all you need
```

Your batch variables stay STRING, without limitations on range or INT/Float

Comment: I'm sorry I wasted your time. I forgot to write that I wanted to address the problem exclusively in cmd, without the use of other programs. I'll now edit the question to include this. Sorry again.

Comment: No problem. I'll keep my answer anyway, maybe it's useful for future visitors. Using pure batch basically means to do it like you would with pen and paper. I forgot decades ago how to do that...

Comment: It should be noted however, that for the end user to perform the same arithmetic calculation as in the OP, they would have to know that `<<` is not correct, and to replace it with `-shl`, i.e. ```call :calc %num% -shl 16```. In doing that, for this specific case, some of the simplicity is lost, (it is not always a like for like arithmetic calculation in both scripting languages).

Comment: @Compo: Einstein uses `<<` as a means to convert floating point numbers to Integer, not as a desired math operation. This step isn't necessary when using PS (or anything else that supports FLOAT). Although I agree, this has to use the syntax of the used secondary language.

Comment: It is arithmetic nonetheless, you said your answer would stay for future visitors for that reason! `x << n` has the effect of multiplying `x` by `2ⁿ`. In this case with `n = 16` thats `x * 65536`. Now of course there's nothing wrong with using `call :calc %num% * 65536`, but doing that would require the end user to make that conversion `2ⁿ` first, hence what I meant by some of the simplicity is lost.